# Access type properties inside initialization that includes a function

Tags: typescript

Not sure how to word this question, so will just show.

Defined an interface as such:

```
export interface IGridInfo<T> {
    results: T;
    pageNumber: int;
    pageSize: int;
    dataSource: any;
}
```

When initializing...

```
myVariable: IGridInfo<IPerson[]> =
{
  results: null,
  pageSize: 100,
  pageNumber: 0,
  dataSource: {
      getData: (params) => {
         this.myVariable.pageNumber = 0;
         this.myVariable.pageSize = 100;
  }}
}
```

Rather than `this.myVariable.pageSize`, would rather do `pageSize` without the `this.myVariable` part.

Tried a few combinations but all result in syntax errors.

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. The closest I can think of would be something like this:

```
getData: function(params) {
    this.pageNumber = 0;
    this.pageSize = 100;
}.bind(this.myVariable)
```

But no way to get rid of the `this`.